# Why does the function only give the value of the first input?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Whenever I try to click on the colors it only gives "White", but it doesn't want to give the other values on screen.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Achtergrondkleur is: " + x;
}
```

```html
<table BORDER="4">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="kleur">Selecteer een kleur!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="radio">
    <td onchange="myFunction()">
      <input id="mySelect" value="Wit" type="radio" class="color">Wit <br>
      <input id="mySelect" value="Grijs" type="radio" class="color">Grijs <br>
      <input id="mySelect" value="Groen" type="radio" class="color">Groen <br>
      <input id="mySelect" value="Geel" type="radio" class="color">Geel <br>
      <input id="mySelect" value="Rood" type="radio" class="color">Rood <br>
      <input id="mySelect" value="Blauw" type="radio" class="color">Blauw <br>
      <input id="mySelect" value="Zwart" type="radio" class="color">Zwart <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="radio">
    <td colspan="2">
      <p id="text"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: HTML 101: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: document.getElementById("mySelect") Will always take the first input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in your code:

- `id` must be unique in the page, so you should replace it with `name`;
- you need to add a `click`-[event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to your elements with "mySelect" `name`.

```js
document.getElementsByName("mySelect").forEach(mySelect => {
  mySelect.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Achtergrondkleur is: " + this.value;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table BORDER="4">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="kleur">Selecteer een kleur!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="radio">
    <td>
      <input name="mySelect" value="Wit" type="radio" class="color">Wit <br>
      <input name="mySelect" value="Grijs" type="radio" class="color">Grijs <br>
      <input name="mySelect" value="Groen" type="radio" class="color">Groen <br>
      <input name="mySelect" value="Geel" type="radio" class="color">Geel <br>
      <input name="mySelect" value="Rood" type="radio" class="color">Rood <br>
      <input name="mySelect" value="Blauw" type="radio" class="color">Blauw <br>
      <input name="mySelect" value="Zwart" type="radio" class="color">Zwart <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="radio">
    <td colspan="2">
      <p id="text"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
```

will just give you the first element because you used the same ID for every element. Your have to give every element a unique ID.